# persistant menu, background and logo over website asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web

Im completely new to web programming, I have an asp.net project im working on and I have a logo at the top, a menu bar underneath and content under that, I don't want to have the user loading up a new menu, logo everytime they change pages within the website, I haven't done any html programming since the 90s and im sure they used to use frames for this effect. can I do this with asp.net?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer to load the menu again each time... is it really that much of an issue for a few bytes of HTML?  All decent browsers will cache the logo.

Read about ASP.NET Master Pages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX

The specific behaviour you want could be achieved with an AJAX update panel which allows part of a web page to be updated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Comment: Master pages is exactly what im looking for thanks, yeah I agree most browsers will cache but I was thinking more about how much code behind for buttons and menus id need, Id rather just have 5 button click events in the entire site instead of having 5 per page, far too much duplicate code, im a bit of a sucker for efficiency. Thanks.